# Microsoft Windows 2012R2 Certificate Authority performance degredation

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

I am developing a program that requests certificates from the Windows 2012R2 CA and during this process I have noticed the time taken to service these request is taking longer.  At present I am requesting batches of between 100 and 1000 certificates, the requesting program is restarted after every batch and as far as I can tell there isn't anything in there that could be causing this issue.

When I start with a fresh installation of Windows it will take around 15 seconds to process 100 requests and issues the certificates.  By the time the CA has issued 5000 certificates it is taking 25 seconds, and by 15000 certificates it is around 40 seconds.  I think that 15000 certs isn't a large number

I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed this?
Is there a setup option for Windows that by installation monkey should be selecting?

Comment: As a test, try configuring the certificate template for "Do not store certificates and requests in the CA database" to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @GregAskew - I'm looking into that and hope to get the results on Monday, many thanks.